# How do I setup a VPC that allows Lambdas to talk to each other and RDS?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

So I have been developing a project in .NET Core with AWS which is a pretty basic web app performing crud operations on a database. I'm currently stuck as I can not get a lambda to call another lambda within the same VPC while also allowing both lambdas access to the same RDS instance.

VPC_A = 3 subnets, all associated with routing tables to an igw
RDS = associated with all 3 subnets mentioned above in VPC_A
Lambda_A = associated with VPC_A & all 3 subnets, able to connect to RDS but NOT Lambda_B
Lambda_B = associated with VPC_A & all 3 subnets, able to connect to RDS

I'm trying to have Lambda_A call Lambda_B, but both lambdas need access to the RDS instance.

If I understand the problem correctly, when I have a lambda attempt to call another Lambda with the AmazonLambdaClient the connection fails as it can't exit the private network of the vpc.

I guess my question comes down to what would a network within AWS look like that allowed lambdas on the same VPC to talk to each other as well as an RDS instance.

Answer (score 3):

Lambda functions do not talk directly to each other.

When one Lambda function invokes another Lambda function, this is done by contacting the Lambda service API, via the Internet.

This means a NAT Gateway is required, in order to enable that access.  Without this, Lambda functions inside a VPC do not have the ability to access anything on the Internet, including the Lambda service API for invoking other functions.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Scenario2.html for diagrams of NAT Gateway deployments.